# Popup doesn't work in chrome sidebar

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When i click on link in chrome sidebar, popup doesn't show up. I'm trying to do authentication through facebook and it's require to open facebook popup to accept the permissions. Is any solution for this? Maybe i should listen to all click events in extension and then open windows with extension?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, by default, blocks most of the pop-ups. You should see a tiny pop-up blocked icon to the right of the address bar. You could either click on that icon to allow that particular pop-up or you could allow pop-ups from settings.

However, if you're in a situation where you can't expect all users to allow pop-ups, you should create a separate link ( `<a target="_blank">` ) that directly opens a pop-up (instead of trying to display a pop-up in code behind)

Comment: well, the link is not in website html, it's in plugin sidebar, and there is no address bar.